# Word meaning 'the day before'

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word meaning 'the day before' that fits within the following sentence:

'day before the day the conference started'

Alternatively a neater way of saying the same thing would be great.

Comment: "The day before the conference started"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the ***eve*** of the conference.

> [**eve**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Eve) *- the evening **or day** preceding a special day, such as a holiday* (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 0):

"The day prior to the start of the conference" is a form often used [this being an example](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/northwest-worldperks/70160-when-does-2-days-prior-begin.html).