# Meaning of ‘eve’

Tags: meaning, word-usage, vocabulary

What is the reason behind using the word *eve* in the following contexts?

> 1. Christmas Eve
> 2. New year Eve

Comment: Didn't you get any clues from the dictionary?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [word meaning 'the day before'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/129864/word-meaning-the-day-before)

Comment: @deadrat - not really that duplicate, this is more on usage based on etymology.

Comment: @Josh61 I don't begrudge you your answer, but the usage seems to have little to do with the etymology.  *Eve* in these cases means "the evening before" and (as you noted) has since time out of mind.  But I've nominated for reopening, which is the best I can do.

Comment: Isn't  'since time out of mind' etymology?

Comment: @Josh61 No, *æfen* is etymology.

Comment: This is why we use comments, post a link to a dictionary. This is general reference, at the very most migrate the question to ELL [English Language Learners](http://english.stackexchange.com/) If users want to be only *helpful* then they can post an answer as "community wiki", they will receive no credit on their rep but their answer will help the OP.

Comment: @deadrat - mmmm...disagreement is the best source of questions :)

Comment: @Josh61 where is the research on this question?

Comment: @Mari-LouA   -       Why we use 'eve' in set phrases like New Year's Eve is not something you can easily understand from a common dictionary. Probably only OED or Etymonline can help in that respect. I'd not  take for granted a new/juniour user is familiar with those sources, should they be? From that my answer.

Comment: @Josh61  She asks if you can use *eve* for birthdays!! And you replied  
*‘Yes, I guess you can’* and then you provide her with a dictionary link to [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/eve). So, is the OP really concerned with the etymology or with its usage? Please note she doesn't mention "origin", the OP is asking "why" *eve* is used in these two particular expressions. Two expressions that are extremely common in the English language.  It's PURE general reference. Now, if the OP wants to modify and improve the question, I think she should do so

Answer (score 3):

Its usage is centuries old as refers to its original meaning of "evening". It is now used with the connotation of evening before an "event":

***[Eve](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=eve&searchmode=none)*** (n.):

> - ***c. 1200, eve "evening," especially the time between sunset and darkness,*** from Old English æfen, with loss of terminal -n (which, though forming part of the stem, perhaps was mistaken for an inflection), from Proto-Germanic *æbando- (cognates: Old Saxon aband, Old Frisian ewnd, Dutch avond, Old High German aband, German Abend, Old Norse aptann, Danish aften), which is of uncertain origin. ***Now superseded in its original sense by evening.***
> - ***Specific meaning "day before a saint's day or festival" is from late 13c. Transferred sense of "the moment right before any event, etc." is by 1780. Even (n.), evening keep the original form.***
> - ***Christmas Eve*** is Middle English Cristenmesse Even (c. 1300).
> - ***New Year's Eve c. 1300;*** "þer þay dronken & dalten ... on nwe gerezeuen."

(Etynomline)

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) can we use eve for birthdays as well?

Comment: Yes, I guess you can. ***Eve*** :http://www.thefreedictionary.com/eve

Comment: We do genref now?

Comment: Do we say "[on my ] birthday eve"? *Really*? Is that common in English? Why/why not?

Comment: ***On the eve of my birthday*** is an expression that is used....ever heard of it?https://www.google.it/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=on%20the%20eve%20of%20my%20birthday

Comment: Read carefully, I asked about "Birthday Eve" or **"[on my] birthday eve"**, following the formula "Xmas Eve" and "New Year's Eve".

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I never wrote  about 'birthday eve'. But why not?https://www.google.it/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=my+birthday+eve

Comment: No, I did because knowing English language learners that would be a logical follow up, I see "Christmas Eve" I discover that the term *eve* meanings the night before an event. Can I say this for birthdays? The answerer replies "I guess so" which is not a clear unequivocal response, *anzi* il contrario; therefore, I the learner, presume that the expression "B/birthday E/eve" is used in English and is well known.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - are you being difficult?

Comment: @Josh61 - I think MariLou is being curious, not difficult. If you read your answer as it is currently written, hers is a natural follow-on question. I'd suggest editing your answer, and addressing it. After all, this is a site about English usage. If you're going to answer such a fundamental question, you may as well discuss modern usage while you're at it.

Comment: @J.R. - "such a fundamental question" was put on hold. My answer addresses the question actually asked. My comments answer its extensions. The second answer addresses  its current usage. If it is reopened it can be updated.

Comment: @Josh61 - You're allowed to edit answers even after questions are put on hold.

Comment: @J.R. - I've done my best to help OP.

Comment: Josh: The comments by @Mari-LouA seemed to be leading you toward an improved answer, one that would make make it even more helpful – for the O.P., and for future visitors. Too bad you've brushed them off and accused her of being "difficult".

Comment: @JR - no comment.

Comment: No comment is the best policy @Josh61.

Answer (score 1):

It means a period time , not only refers to the night

1. **the day before:**
   "he always arrives on the eve of her departure"
2. **the period immediately before something:**
   "on the eve of the French Revolution"
3. **the latter part of the day** (the period of decreasing daylight from late afternoon until nightfall)

Source: [Mnemonic Dictionary](http://www.mnemonicdictionary.com/word/eve)