# How is evening even?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I get that the origins of the word evening (being late in the day) [come from](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=evening) *æfen*.

But this seems to have [intersected with another word](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=even) meaning 'making balanced' or 'making fair.

> They went through a process of *evening* it out

How did the two meanings converge on the one word like this? (To make balanced and late in the day).

My question is: **How is evening even?**

Comment: Have you looked up the etymology of the adjective *even* (from which your verb is derived)?

Comment: *Evening* can be a gerund or a noun.

Comment: Related (not a duplicate): "[Meaning of ‘eve’](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/285073/meaning-of-eve)"

Comment: I have included the research in my question. Could you explain why you've closed my question for not doing research?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How is evening even?

It's not. These are *homonyms*, two different words with the same pronunciation and spelling.

*Even*, verb, is a recategorization of *even*, adjective, from OE *efen*, "level", conjectured to have derived from a Proto-Germanic form **ebnaz*.

*Evening*, noun, is the modern form of OE *æfnung*, gerund form of *æfnian* "grow toward nighttime", derived from *æfn*, "nighttime" conjectured to have derived from a Proto-Germanic form **æbando* or **æbinjo*. *Æfn* developed into ME/EModE *even* and *eve*, but outside of poetic use these were superseded by *evening* in Modern English.

See *OED*, s.v. **Eve**, **Even**, **Evening**