# What is the meaning of "eve"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning for "eve" in the phrase "Merry Christmas Eve".

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of ‘eve’](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/285073/meaning-of-eve)

Answer (score 1):

According to the Merriam-Webster dictionary, in the context of "Christmas Eve", "[eve](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eve)" means:

> the evening or the day before a special day